# JSF HTTP Session Login

Tags: jsf

I try to create login form in web application.
in JSP page I can use

```
<%
   String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
   session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
%>
```

but now I am using JSF /Facelets  for web application 
I don't know how to create session in JSF Backing bean for client and check if user is logged in or not so it will redirect into login page.
who can help me give me link tutorial for these problem ?
thank you before

Now I have little problem with mapping into web.xml
code snipped of class Filter

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.config = filterConfig;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    LoginController controller = (LoginController) req.getSession()
            .getAttribute("loginController");
    if (controller == null || !controller.isLoggedIn()) {
        res.sendRedirect("../admin/login.xhtml");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and in `web.xml` I map with `<fitler>` tag

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>userLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mcgraw.controller.UserLoginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginPage</param-name>
        <param-value>/login.xhtml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>userLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have one folder admin in web project and I check if the user is not logged in with admin permission to not access page (I can do the permission check) but when I use the filter the browser doesn't understand url ??
no StackTrace show when the browser doesn't understand url

Error shown on Firefox

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

on IE it loading ... loading . ..  non-stop

now I change condition which check if req.getPathInfo.startsWith("/login.xhtml") it will do chain

I have 2 idea but it response 500 HTTP STATUS

```
 if (controller == null || !controller.isLoggedIn()) {
     res.sendRedirect("../admin/login.xhtml");
     if(req.getPathInfo().startsWith("/login.xhtml")){
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

} else {
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

===============

```
if (controller == null || !controller.isLoggedIn()) {
    if (!req.getPathInfo().startsWith("/login.xhtml")) {
        res.sendRedirect("../admin/login.xhtml");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

======================
update Class loginController

```
package com.mcgraw.controller;

import com.DAO.UserBean;
import com.entity.IUser;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 * @author Kency
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private UserBean userBean;
    private IUser user;
    private boolean admin;
    private boolean mod;
    private PasswordService md5;

    /** Creates a new instance of LoginController */
    public LoginController() {
        user = new IUser();
        md5 = new PasswordService();
    }

    // getter / setter
    public boolean isMod() {
        return mod;
    }

    public void setMod(boolean mod) {
        this.mod = mod;
    }

    public IUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(IUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public String cplogin() {
        String md5Password = md5.md5Password(user.getPassword());
        if (userBean.userLogin(user.getUsername(), md5Password) != null) {
            if (user.getUsername() != null || md5Password != null) {
                user = userBean.userLogin(user.getUsername(), md5Password);
                if (user.getGroups().getAdmin() != null) {
                    setAdmin(user.getGroups().getAdmin());
                }
                if (user.getGroups().getMods() != null) {
                    setMod(user.getGroups().getMods());
                }
                if (isAdmin() == true || isMod() == true) {
                    return "home";
                } else {
                    return "login";
                }
            } else {
                return "login";
            }
        } else {
            return "login";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        user = null;
        return "login";
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return user != null;
    }
}
```

I have new problem if render JSF taglib with method loggedIn, in index page (not in admin folder) user doesn't login can see what I render example,  <== this like if user doesn't login user can't see but why can he see it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can in JSF get/set HTTP session attributes via [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap--) which is basically a wrapper around `HttpSession#get/setAttribute()`.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    public String login() {
        User user = userService.find(username, password);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (user == null) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again"));
            username = null;
            password = null;
            return null;
        } else {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
            return "userhome?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "index?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the Facelets page, just bind the `username` and `password` input fields to this bean and invoke `login()` action accordingly.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{loginController.username}" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{loginController.password}" />
    <h:commandButton value="login" action="#{loginController.login}" />
</h:form>
```

Session attributes are directly accessible in EL. A session attribute with name `user` is in EL available as `#{user}`. When testing if the user is logged in some `rendered` attribute, just check if it's `empty` or not.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty user}">
    <p>Welcome, #{user.fullName}</p>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="logout" action="#{loginController.logout}" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The logout action basically just trashes the session.

---

As to checking an incoming request if a user is logged in or not, just create a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which does roughly the following in [`doFilter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-javax.servlet.FilterChain-) method:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

    boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

    if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
    }
}
```

Map it on an `url-pattern` covering the restricted pages, e.g. `/secured/*`, `/app/*`, etc.

#### See also:

- [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)
- [Authorization redirect on session expiration does not work on submitting a JSF form, page stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580267/authorization-redirect-on-session-expiration-does-not-work-on-submitting-a-jsf-f/)

Comment: hi BalusC all it ok but i have little problem with map to web.xml page you can see above question i was edit, i have folder admin in web project and redirect to  ../admin/login.xhtml it not work browser dont understand it

Comment: If the login page is placed in `/admin`, then the same filter will be invoked again and it will go in an infinite redirect loop because the user isn't logged in. Either place the login page outside the `/admin` or add a condition which checks if `req.getPathInfo().startsWith("/login.xhtml")` and then just continue the chain and don't redirect.

Comment: once again i was edited my question with solution you suggest but i retrieve error 500 HTTP Status in glassfish server it throws Null Pointer Exception

Comment: OK, the pathinfo is apparently `null` in your filter. Use `req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login.xhtml")` instead.

Comment: thank you for your support ! but when it redirect to login.xhtml i true but i want chang extension to login.jsf

Comment: Just change it accordingly in the URL's in the filter.

Comment: oh i missing mapped `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>` and edit in filter class, once again thank you very much

Comment: Hi Balusc I have new Problem with it, userlogin above i use for admincp but when i access to main page( it out of admincp folder) example content/register.xhtml it redirect me to http://localhost/content/admin/login.jsf. how can i avoid redirect in page out of admincp folder, i was map in web.xml url-partern is `<url-partern>/admin/*</url-partern>` Thank you!

Comment: Redirect to `/content/login.jsf` or `../login.jsf` instead.

Comment: Hi Balusc i do it but i repeat loading to login.jsf http://localhost/myproject/admin/login.jsf, in firefox i get message `The page isn't redirecting properly` , true url redirect in filter is `res.sendRedirect("../admin/login.jsf");`

Comment: and i have problem with logout, when i logout user is null and re-login it throws Exception target null user.username. why error? Thank you

Comment: The first error is caused because you're redirecting to the login page in an infinite loop. You have to either move the login page outside the url-pattern of the filer or check inside the filter if the currently requested page is not the login page. As to the logout, just add a `if (user != null)` check before accessing the user.

Comment: Thank you , i move login in other folder of admin folder and other page inside content folder. it work well Thank you

Comment: Where do i add `if(user !=null)` ? login method or logout method? i try with logout and login but it not work

Comment: Just there where `NullPointerException` was caused because `user` is `null`.

Comment: Hi BalusC i get exception `WARNING: /admin/login.xhtml @43,73 value="#{loginController.user.username}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null` i dont know where i can add user != null, i was updated question with code. GoodNight BalusC Thank You!

Comment: That's not a `NullPointerException`. The `#{loginController.user}` just returned `null` and therefore it's impossible to set `#{loginController.user.username}`. You need to ensure that `#{loginController.user}` never returns null. Usually, you'd like to preinitialize nested beans during declaration or bean's construction or postconstruct like `user = new User()`. And.. in the future, please ask a new question for each independent problem :)

Comment: Thank you ! but i was preinitialize it in constructor and when end-user call method login, user set to null in this method user=null and user is global varialbe when user logout it set to null therefore loginController.user is null,i know it, but i dont know how to re-initial it to user = new User(); After this problem i will post each question for independent problem :) Thank You

Comment: You'd like to approach this problem a bit differently. Instead of relying on the presence of the `User` to check if someone is logged in or not, use for example `if (user.getId() != null)`. On logout, just do `user = new User()` to prepare the login fields.

Comment: UserService cannot be resolved to a type - what import/jar is missing? thanx

Comment: @Li3ro: it was just exemplary. Write it yourself. It's a simple `@Stateless` EJB which does the persistence works (by e.g. JPA or maybe plain old JDBC).

Comment: How 'secure' is this one?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your backing bean when a request is received (like in an action method):

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Then you can work with the request and session objects just like you used to with JSPs, setting attributes and so on.

You might also want to take a look at my [related question about checking the client session in a servlet Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806033/how-do-i-make-client-browser-stop-requesting-an-expired-session-id). You could write a similar Filter to check for the user login in their HttpSession and then do a redirect (or RequestDispatch like I ended up doing) to your login page if needed.

Comment: HttpSession have method setAttribute() the same session in jSP but how can i maintain and check session in client ?

Comment: @Kency I'm not understanding what it was you were doing before. Can you edit your question and provide some of your old code? When you say "check session in client", do you actually mean that you are checking something on the client-side using JavaScript?

Comment: i was find phaselistenter to check user login for JSF. My question is when user access web page via web browser jsf will check user login or not it means in jsp i write 1 page session.getAttribute("thename") and include it in header page where i want to check user login or not login.  But use phaselistener will check it but now i not yet understand phaselistener work.  you have tutorial link for JSF login session,if any? if you have give me link to tutorial thank you