# How can I call doFilter() in index.xthml

Tags: java, jsf

I involved in `JSF` Login application. Here there are two methods call `doLogin()` that is include the *login* logic and `doFilter()` inside the `LoginBean` class. And in the `index.xhtml` there is an command button called `login` and here I used this. `action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"`, So I can call `doLogin()`.My problem is How can I call `doFilter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a managed bean like this:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class Login {

    public Login() {
    }

    public String doLogin() {
    }

    public void doFilter() {
    }
}
```

If you need to call `doFilter` method inside `doLogin`, just add the call like in basic programming:

```
public String doLogin() {
    //some code here...
    doFilter();
    //more code over here...
}
```

---

Based in your last question: [Primefaces Login Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667449/primefaces-login-application), you're confusing the `doFilter` method that belongs to the Web Filter and the `doLogin` method that belongs to a managed bean:

- The `doLogin` will be invoked by the FacesServlet when the user activate an event that it calls this method. For example, an UI command action:

  ```html
  <h:form>
      <h:commandButton value="Click me!" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" />
  </h:form>
  ```
- The `doFilter` method will be invoked by the Web Filter. Note that a Filter will be executed before the (Faces)Servlet if and only if the request URL matches with the URLPattern declared in the Web Filter. This means:

  - We have a filter with URLPattern = "*.xhtml"
  - Everytime I make a request to `<whatever>.xhtml`, the Filter will be invoked.
  - When invoked, it will execute the `doFilter` method (default method).

More info:

- [Java web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958854/1065197) by BalusC. (I recommend you to read the links inside the answer).
- [Java Servlet Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) in our wiki page.
- [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) in our wiki page.
- [JSF HTTP Session Login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3841361/1065197) by BalusC.
- [JSF: How control access and rights in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522629/1065197) by BalusC.

As a side note: You really have to learn the basics on Java Web Development **and** the best practices.