# Session scoped bean not stored in user session

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters, session-bean

I tried to develop a simple authentification application based on BaluC's answer in [JSF HTTP Session Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841361/jsf-http-session-login), but the problem is that my session scoped bean `UserManager` is not stored in the user session, so when the `LoginFilter` checks if the user is logged in,

`UserManager userManager=(UserManager)req.getSession().getAttribute("userManager");`

it returns `null` !

Any Idea on how to fix this problem ?

Comment: In that example he has given name of the bean as `user`. Try to get like `UserManager userManager=(UserManager)req.getSession().getAttribute("user");`

Comment: And If you are new to JSF first go through some tutorials. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/

Comment: I fixed the answer over there.

Comment: @BalusC the problem is not resolved yet ! the `SessionScoped Bean` `userManager` is created several times ! Indeed, the `init` function which is declared `@PostConstruct` is executed many times ! so the `loggedin` property is reinitialized !

Comment: Apparently you used the wrong annotation package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get it from the context like :

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

UserManager userManager = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{userManager}", UserManager.class);
```