# Session scoped managed bean not available as session attribute in filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, managed-bean, session-scope

After following the [JSF HTTP Session Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841361/jsf-http-session-login) tutorial, i tried clicking on pages and it redirected me always to the login page (without css). I tried debugging using the code below:

```
Enumeration<String> attributeNames = wrappedRequest.getSession().getAttributeNames();
    while(attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                System.out.println(attributeNames.nextElement());
    }
```

and found that the class I expected to be return at

```
ConnectionManager manager = (ConnectionManager) wrappedRequest.getSession()
            .getAttribute("connectionManager");
```

wasn't returned. Some other class was returned instead of ConnectionManager class as seen in the server log.

```
Info:   employeeManager
Info:   org.jboss.weld.context.beanstore.http.LockStore
Info:   com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap
Info:   org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
Info:   org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations
Info:   javax.faces.request.charset
```

EmployeeManager is another managed bean. Can I know why this is return instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer was based on the `ConnectionManager` being a JSF managed bean. However, based on presence of CDI-specific objects in the session, it looks like that you're using CDI `@Named` instead of JSF `@ManagedBean` to manage beans (which is at its own a Good Thing though).

You could just `@Inject` it into the filter instead of manually grabbing it from the HTTP session.

```
@Inject
private ConnectionManager connectionManager;
```

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class)
- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named/4347707#4347707)